# its showing not valid at this position for this server version

Tags: mysql

```
(select M.MName 'Movie', S.SName 'Staff Name' from movie as M 
left join screen_movie as sc 
left join booking as b 
left join staff as S
on M.MovieID = screen_movie.MovieID and sc.screen_Movie_ID = b.screen_Movie_ID  and b.SID = S.SID)
union
(select M.MName 'Movie', S.SName 'Staff Name' from movie as M 
right join screen_movie as sc 
right join booking as b 
right join staff as S
on M.MovieID = screen_movie.MovieID and sc.screen_Movie_ID = b.screen_Movie_ID  and b.SID = S.SID);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try move the on clause for each table and remove () around each select

```
 select M.MName 'Movie'
  , S.SName 'Staff Name' 
  from movie as M 
  left join screen_movie  as sc  ON  M.MovieID = sc.MovieID 
  left join booking as b ON sc.screen_Movie_ID = b.screen_Movie_ID 
  left join staff as S ON b.SID = S.SID 
union
  select M.MName 'Movie'
  , S.SName 'Staff Name' 
  from movie as M 
  right join screen_movie  as sc on M.MovieID = sc.MovieID
  right join booking as b  ON sc.screen_Movie_ID = b.screen_Movie_ID
  right join staff as S ON b.SID = S.SID
```